# Strategies for overflowing content in CSS3 multi-column

Tags: css, overflow, css-multicolumn-layout

I am trying to setup multi-column layout using the new multi-column layout. But is there anyway to allow flexible widths for the created columns?
All strategies I've seen online always result in fixed-width layouts, even when the content overflows the column.

```css
ul {
    -webkit-column-width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>element</li>
    <li>elementthat'stoolong</li>
    <li>element</li>
    <li>element</li>
    <li>element</li>
    <li>element</li>
    <li>element</li>
    <li>element</li>
</ul>
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/3UeaY/)

Comment: I found the question difficult to understand, could you link to the example of the fixed layout which you are trying to make fluid?

Comment: This is for a chrome extension so I can't link to anything directly.  

In the jsfiddle though, it shows the one long element being cut off, but I would like the column width to expand to show it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to do this so I went back to my previous solution of paging the results into `<div>`s and then having each of those pages sized as wide as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent text from overflowing, try:

```
li {
word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Column width can be set not only in pixels but also in % and em, allowing for more flexible layout. To prevent content from collapsing entirely, you would of course set a min-width.
According to [W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/), content in the normal flow that extends into column gaps (e.g., long words or images) is clipped in the middle of the column gap.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I _want_ it to overflow, and then expand the contents. I'm thinking there might not be away to do it natively though.